# Update the global variable in Rospy

Tags: python-2.7, rospy

i have the problem. I have two node, node 1 and node2, where node1 send a float number in node2 and node2 send a float number in node1. In the function callback, I want sum the information received with other value and update the variable. But the problem is that i don't succeed the information sent, because the terminal prints in output only first update(for node 1 i get 2.9, and node 2 2.0)
These code for node1 and node2

```
Node1
    !/usr/bin/env python
    import rospy
    import time
    from std_msgs.msg import Float64 
    global x1
    global a 
    x1 = 1.5
    def callback(msg):
        #print 'Sto ricevendo informazioni da %s nel tempo %s' % (msg.data, time.ctime())
         #print "%f"%msg.data
        a = msg.data  
        info_nodo2 = a + 0.5
        x1 = info_nodo2
        print "%f"%x1  
    def nodo():
        pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter1', Float64)
        rospy.init_node('nodo1', anonymous=True)
        rospy.loginfo("In attesa")
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter2', Float64, callback)
        rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 10hz
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            for i in range(1,51):   
                #rospy.loginfo(num)
                pub.publish(x1)
                rate.sleep()
            rospy.spin()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            nodo()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            pass
```

```
 Node2

    import rospy
    import time
    from std_msgs.msg import Float64
    global x2 
    global a 
    x2 = 2.4
    def callback(msg):
        #print 'Sto ricevendo informazioni da %s nel tempo %s' % (msg.data, time.ctime())
         #print "%f"%msg.data     
        a = msg.data  
        info_nodo1 = a + 0.5
        x2 = info_nodo1
        print "%f"%x2
    def nodo():
        pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter2', Float64)
        rospy.init_node('nodo2', anonymous=True)
        rospy.loginfo("In attesa")
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter1', Float64, callback) 
        rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 10hz   
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            for i in range(1,51):
               # num = "%s" % (x2)
                #rospy.loginfo(num)
                pub.publish(x2)
                rate.sleep()
            rospy.spin() 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            nodo()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            pass
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you are declaring `x1` and `x2` as `global` variables. At every iteration their values get reset to `1.5` and `2.4`, respectively. Thus, the published values are those values plus the `0.5` (i.e `2.0` and `2.9`).

If I understand correctly, you want the two nodes to continuously update each others values (for `x1` and `x2`). I wrote your nodes as classes instead and replaced the global variables by instance variables:

**Node1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import rospy
import std_msgs.msg


class Nodo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Params
        self.x1 = 1.5
        self.a = None

        # Node cycle rate (in Hz).
        self.loop_rate = rospy.Rate(10)

        # Publishers
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher("~chatter1", std_msgs.msg.Float64, queue_size=10)

        # Subscribers
        rospy.Subscriber("~chatter2", std_msgs.msg.Float64, self.callback)

    def callback(self, msg):
        self.a = msg.data
        self.x1 = self.a + 0.5
        rospy.loginfo("x1: {}".format(self.x1))

    def start(self):
        rospy.loginfo("In attesa")

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            for ii in xrange(1, 51):
                self.pub.publish(self.x1)
                self.loop_rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("nodo1", anonymous=True)
    my_node = Nodo()
    my_node.start()
```

**Node2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import rospy
import std_msgs.msg


class Nodo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Params
        self.x2 = 2.4
        self.a = None

        # Node cycle rate (in Hz).
        self.loop_rate = rospy.Rate(10)

        # Publishers
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher("~chatter2", std_msgs.msg.Float64, queue_size=10)

        # Subscribers
        rospy.Subscriber("~chatter1", std_msgs.msg.Float64, self.callback)

    def callback(self, msg):
        self.a = msg.data
        self.x2 = self.a + 0.5
        rospy.loginfo("x2: {}".format(self.x2))

    def start(self):
        rospy.loginfo("In attesa")

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            for ii in xrange(1, 51):
                self.pub.publish(self.x2)
                self.loop_rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("nodo2", anonymous=True)
    my_node = Nodo()
    my_node.start()
```

When running these two nodes the console output is as follows:

```
process[nodo_1-1]: started with pid [7688]
process[nodo_2-2]: started with pid [7689]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.627418] In attesa
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.627904] In attesa
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.725064] x2: 2.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.725512] x1: 2.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.825050] x2: 3.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.825448] x1: 3.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.925056] x2: 4.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865725.925608] x1: 4.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.025061] x2: 5.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.025617] x1: 5.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.125045] x2: 6.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.125605] x1: 6.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.225033] x2: 7.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.225586] x1: 7.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.325013] x2: 8.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.325606] x1: 8.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.425041] x2: 9.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.425608] x1: 9.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.525057] x2: 10.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.525545] x1: 10.5
[INFO] [WallTime: 1478865726.625054] x2: 11.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm very new to ROS and am trying to build a ROS node as both a subscriber and publisher. Is it recognized as bad practice to achieve this by having global `pub` and `sub` variables? Or would it be better to pass `pub` as an argument to the `callback`? Or does one have to go your way and use classes?